# How to get the choice(value) out of datalist in javascript?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, datalist

I am developing a probability calculator and I can't manage to get the 'value' out of the datalist. I'm very new to javascript so maybe it's very easy but I don't know how to do it yet.

I tried using object.value but it does not seem to work. Do you have any ideas?

Here's my javascript code:

```js
//test
let test = document.getElementById("name");
test.addEventListener("input", () => console.log(test.value));

// variables
let q = document.getElementById("submit");
let q1 = document.getElementById("q1");

q.addEventListener('click', () => console.log("works"));
q.addEventListener('click', probability_calculation()));

function probability_calculation() {
  if (q1.value === 'Rap') {
    alert("works");
    console.log("works well");
  } else if (q1.value === 'Alter') {
    console.log('33%');
  } else if (q1.value === 'Pop') {
    console.log('97%');
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="header">Probability Calculator</h1>
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" id="name">
  <input list="q1" placeholder="What is your favourite type of music?">
</div>
<panel class="center-q">
  <datalist id="q1">
            <option>Rap</option>
            <option>Alter</option>
            <option>Pop</option>
        </datalist>
</panel>
<input type="submit" id="submit">
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to check the browser developer console (F12) for errors. The messages there can help you pinpoint problems with your code.  And if you run your snippet the error is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'" for the reason given in @zavg answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
q.addEventListener('click', probability_calculation()));
```

- You have an extra closing parentheses character
- You should not call `probability_calculation` function but just pass it itself as a callback handler to event listener

The correct version is

```
q.addEventListener('click', probability_calculation);
```

Also, you have two tags with the same identifier `q1`.

I simplified your `datalist` stuff to simple `select` in order to show the working version.

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9odgf1tc)